# unix command to replace contents in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file *hello.txt* with content:

```
"this-is-prod-env" : "yes"
"this-is-devl-env" : "yes"
```

I need replace the value in `"this-is-prod-env" : "yes"` with `no`. The output should be `"this-is-prod-env" : "no"`. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you need to replace all the 'yes' or only the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat input
 "this-is-prod-env" : "yes" "this-is-devl-env" : "yes"
$ sed -E 's/("this-is-prod-env" *: )"yes"/\1"no"/' input
 "this-is-prod-env" : "no" "this-is-devl-env" : "yes"
$ cat input2
 "this-is-prod-env" : "yes"
 "this-is-devl-env" : "yes"
$ sed '/this-is-prod-env/s/yes/no/' input2
 "this-is-prod-env" : "no"
 "this-is-devl-env" : "yes"
```

The first solution will work with both files, but the 2nd is more idiomatic.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the input was supposed to be spread over multiple lines, but didn't show as such because not in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

With Perl:

```
perl -i.old -pe 's/yes/no/ if /-prod-/' hello.txt
```

`-i.old` edits the file inline and saves the old version of the file with the `.old` suffix (a very useful option if you messed something up)

`s/yes/no if /-prod-/` substitutes `yes` for `no` if the line contains `-prod-`